# Do native speakers use "that" as a relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

Do native speakers use "that" as a relative clause?

What would you prefer?

> I know THAT you just sent me a message a few minutes ago.

Or

> I know you just sent me a message a few minutes ago.

Comment: In your example "(that) you just sent me a message a few minutes ago" is not a relative clause but a content clause as complement of "know".

Comment: @BillJ so how is it called in English? And is it okay to use "that", or would be superfluous?

Comment: It's called a 'subordinator' in both relative and content clauses. Its function is that of 'marker'. In many sentences it is optional, as it is here.

Comment: @BillJ thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We *don't* usually include the optional "conjunction? subordinator?" ***that*** in simple contexts like OP's example. [Thus...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20know%20you%20did%2CI%20know%20that%20you%20did&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

I can't meaningfully provide any kind of "summary totals" for contexts where we *are* likely to include ***that*** (more *complex* contexts where explicitly including the conjunction is likely to help the reader parse an utterance), because most such contexts are *relatively uncommon*. But consider, for example,...

> *He said as he came in and wiped his feet [**that**] he wouldn't stay long.*

Syntactically speaking, that sentence is perfectly valid with or without ***that***, but we'd almost always include it as an aid to parsing. It's irrelevant for our purposes here that we *could* make the sentence easier to parse simply by rearranging the sequence of elements to position *what* he said immediately after ***He said...***

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for your very detailed answer! Thank you!